# After arriving at JFK on an international flight, what happens with my through-checked baggage?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, international-travel, connecting-flights, domestic-travel

I have booked a flight from Athens to Raleigh-Durham. I have to change airplanes 3 times. The first two flights are with Qatar Airways and the third with American Airlines. My final destination is Raleigh-Durham.

Do I have to collect my baggage and go through Customs and Immigration at the JFK airport before getting the flight to Raleigh-Durham? Do I have to re-check my bags?

The e-ticket says under the baggage allowance that my baggage will be send from ATH to RDU.

Answer (score 2):

If you enter the US at JFK, you will have to pick up your luggage there after passport control and pass customs.  After it, you will be able to drop off your baggage again to be transferred to your final flight (given that it has been checked through, i.e. RDU appears on the baggage tag).